# Maximizing Runespan gains?

Tags: runescape

There is quite some data around on what runes are best to siphon from what islands in the runespan for xp/hour depending on runecrafting level, but I am failing to find to find similar information for maximising runespan points - and I doubt it is the same!

Reason is I want to move up the title track asap.

Answer (score 1):

On the [wiki](https://runescape.wiki/w/Runespan) it says the max amount of xp that can be gained per hour is 138k if you harvest from [Undead Souls](https://runescape.wiki/w/Undead_soul). Doing this can either grant you a Death Rune or Soul Rune which are worth 2.5 and 3.5 points respectively.

Assuming you do actually get 138k per hour, and you get an even amount of death and soul runes, you will get approximately 399.5 xp per 2 siphons (one death and one soul).

So `138,000 / 399.5 ~ 345` of each rune type.

Then if you add up the points `(345 * 2.5) + (345 * 3.5)` you get approximately **2,070 points/hr**.

*Note this answer assumes a Runecrafting level of 99. Also, keep in mind this answer assumes you will get equal amounts of death and soul runes and that you will not fail a siphon in that hour, so YMMV when doing this.*

Comment: Is that the BEST rate, though? Is there no chance I could get more, say, nature runes even if they are worth less individually?

Comment: I believe that is something that would have to be determined on your own. The wiki states the best xp rate is from harvesting from undead souls, meaning that more than likely this is also the best point rate. If you calculate it out for nature runes using the same method I did, you would get a smaller point rate because they are not worth as many points.